# How to make a button that, when clicked, opens the %appdata% directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, jframe

I have made a button, but I don't now how to make it open a specific directory like `%appdata%` when the button is clicked on.

Here is the code ->

```
//---- button4 ----
        button4.setText("Texture Packs");
        button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JFileChooser fileChooser=new JFileChooser("%appdata%");
                int status = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
                fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);

                if(status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    // do something on the selected file.
                }


            }
```

And I want to make something like this ->

```
private void button4MouseClicked(MouseEvent e) throws IOException {

           open folder %appdata% 
           // Open the folder in the file explorer not in Java.
           // When I click on the button, the folder is viewed with the file explorer on the screen
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to open the file selector, or the system file explorer?

Comment: I want to open in system file explorer

Comment: I wrote a [FileExplorer class](http://textu.be/6) for that purpose around a month ago.  I also posted a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Vulcan At just over 50 lines of well formatted, commented code, that is short enough to include in an answer.  I don't think your approach is optimal for any 1.6+ (Use [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class) JRE, but if the OP needs support for pre 1.6..

Comment: @AndrewThompson It is included in an answer as well, but thanks for pointing that out. I forgot the question was to reveal a directory rather than a specific file, which is what my code is designed to do (Desktop#open executes files with related applications, and directories with file explorers).

Comment: Why did you create a [duplicate post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967263/how-can-open-appdata-folder-with-a-button)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;

public class OpenAppData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Horribly platform specific.
        String appData = System.getenv("APPDATA");
        File appDataDir = new File(appData);
        // Get a sub-directory named 'texture'
        File textureDir = new File(appDataDir, "texture");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(textureDir);
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use the 2nd `File` constructor shown in the edit, though it matters little if this is only intended for Windows.  Otherwise, either find an environment variable for that platform, or offer a file chooser.

Answer (score 1):

Execute a command using Runtime.exec(..).  However, not every OS has the same file explorer, so you need to handle the OS.

Windows: `Explorer /select, file`

Mac: `open -R file`

Linux: `xdg-open file`

I wrote a FileExplorer class for the purpose of revealing files in the native file explorer, but you'll need to edit it to detect operating system.
http://textu.be/6

NOTE: This is if you wish to reveal individual files.  To reveal directories, `Desktop#open(File)` is far simpler, as posted by Andrew Thompson.

Comment: Your code from http://textu.be/6 is no longer available. Consider reposting it on another host or including it in your answer (or just remove informations about it from your answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Vista and higher,  `System.getenv("APPDATA");` will return you `C:\Users\(username}\AppData\Roaming`, so you should go one time up, and use this path for `filechooser`, 
Just a simple modified Andrew's example,

```
    String appData = System.getenv("APPDATA");
    File appDataDir = new File(appData); // TODO: this path should be changed! 
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(appData);
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
```

More about [windows xp](http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/environment-variables.html), and [windows vista/7/8](http://windows7tips.com/environment-variables-windows-vista-7.html)