# Open directory in CMD with Java

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd

How can I open **CMD** and get a **Directory** with a Java Code?

I've already tried:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Cmd.exe /c C/Users/me/Desktop/myFile")
```

Comment: I don't mean to state the obvious, but this won't be compatible with other operating systems and might not be the best approach to whatever you're doing.

Comment: If I solved your problem please give an accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a button that, when clicked, opens the %appdata% directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966999/how-to-make-a-button-that-when-clicked-opens-the-appdata-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Desktop` class:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Users\me\Desktop\myFolder"));
```